# grailsuser MissingPropertyException

Tags: grails, spring-security

I am trying to use `<sec:loggedInUserInfo field="firstName"/>` and I am getting MissingPropertyException.  I extended User and have in configured as below.  I am not sure what I am missing...

resources.groovy

```
preAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider(org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider) {
        preAuthenticatedUserDetailsService = ref('preAuthenticatedUserDetailsService')
    }

preAuthenticatedUserDetailsService(org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsByNameServiceWrapper) {
        userDetailsService = ref('userService' )
    }

userService(org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.springsecurity.GormUserDetailsService){
        grailsApplication = ref('grailsApplication')
    }
```

I also have my domain classes configured in Config.groovy

```
grails.plugins.springsecurity.providerNames = ['preAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider' ,'anonymousAuthenticationProvider']

// Added by the Spring Security Core plugin:
grails.plugins.springsecurity.userLookup.userDomainClassName = 'com.administration.AuthUser'
grails.plugins.springsecurity.userLookup.authorityJoinClassName = 'com.administration.AuthUserAuthRole'
grails.plugins.springsecurity.authority.className = 'com.administration.AuthRole'
```

Comment: how your `AuthUser` looks like?

Comment: Did you extend the `GrailsUser` and implemented a custom `GrailsUserDetailsService` as described in the [docs](http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/guide/userDetailsService.html)? If yes - please provide some more code ...